# What does Airbnb mean by "0.5 bathrooms"?

Tags: airbnb

I see "0.5 bathrooms" on the options on filtering the search results.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the same as in real estate listings. That it's only a sink and a commode, no shower or bathtub. Also known as a "powder room".

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathroom#Variations_and_terminology

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it means a half bathroom, that is a bathroom with a toilet and a sink, but no bathtub or shower.

See references like:

- http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-half-bathroom.htm
- http://www.trulia.com/voices/Property_QandA/What_does_it_Mean_Bath_-535484
- Alse see the *Variations* or *Regional differences > Terminology in the United States* sections on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathroom